# Import {jsmpeg} from 'jsmpeg-player'

Tags: angular, jsmpeg

do you have any idea why import is not working in Angular?

ERROR:

Error: src/app/customers/customers.component.ts:4:22 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'jsmpeg-player'. 'C:/Users/adabi/OneDrive/Bureau/Angular/Aximum/angular11/node_modules/jsmpeg-player/build/jsmpeg-player.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jsmpeg-player` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'jsmpeg-player';`

4 import {jsmpeg} from 'jsmpeg-player';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
// @ts-ignore
import JSMpeg from 'jsmpeg-player';
```

Comment: it accepts import but I have the impression that  doesn't work
 I am using for example
 let player = new JSMpeg.Player ('ws: // localhost: 9999', {
       canvas: this.streaming, autoplay: true, audio: false, loop: true
     })
there are no errors but I can't display live camera rtsp

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
import JSMpeg from 'jsmpeg-player';
```

or

```
declare var 'jsmpeg-player';
```

> I think this npm has been deprecated please use the latest one if
> not its fine working on it.

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't work
for the npm I use the version 6.14.11